# Podio API: how to search in all fields except item comments?

Tags: podio

I need to search for a text within a particular workspace. I need all items and fields, **except comments**.

I'm using php-wrapper for Podio API and [Search in space](https://developers.podio.com/doc/search/search-in-space-v2-155195763) function:

```
$attributes = array(
    "query" => $query,
    "ref_type" => "item", // I need just items, not tasks, statuses etc.
    "search_fields" => "title"
);

$items = PodioSearchResult::space( $space_id, $attributes );
```

If `search_fields` parameter will be removed, it will search not only in titles, but in all fields. However, it will also search in comments left for each item and return that items as a result. But I need just results based on fileds values.

Of course, it is possible to list all the fields needed in `search_fields`. But there is a dozen of apps with a dozen of different fields each in that space. Moreover, fields could be added, edited or removed by workspace users. So it looks like a very rough and hard-coded solutiuon to list all the fields.

Is there another way to avoid comments in search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podio doesn't have specific method to avoid only comments. But instead of hardcoding all the fields, you can query dynamically "Get app values" call and use the result in "search_fields".

Comment: Docs says that [Get app values](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-app-values-22455) is depricated and [Search references](https://developers.podio.com/doc/reference/search-references-13312595) should be used instead. However, that might be an approach. At least it is indeed better than hardcoding. Thanks :)